# Should smartphones with AI assistants be restricted for use in office?

Tags: data-leakage, smartphone

New Galaxy S8 & S8+ provide Samsung's new AI assistant called Bixby. This thing was claimed to upload photos and voice records to somewhere. Is it a risk for company confidential information leakage? What about others like Siri, Cortana, Google Assistant? Does it make sense to restrict all of them in offices? They can't be controlled in regard to what they send and how companies owning them use gathered information. I'm not law expert, but some user privacy agreements look very fuzzy and therefore suspicious (i.e. Samsung Bixby's)

Comment: AI is kind of a buzzword, and doesn't apply to all mentioned, but application behavior is the concern anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes. Any recording device that you do not control should not be used where the information it records is sensitive.